# Excel 2010 Formula of 3 variables with 3 results

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I haven't been able to figure out how to combine these logic & date formulas in 1 cell.

- My parameters would be:

  - A2 will always have a manually entered date in it
  - B2 could have one of three manually entered data in it

    1. A date (mm/dd/yy)
    2. BLANK (as in nothing because the date is unknown)
    3. "N/A" (as in a date is not applicable for that entry)
- The results I need in C2 is one of three  options

  1. The result of the formula =NETWORK(A2,B2)
  2. "UNKNOWN" because there should be a date in B2 but there isn't to calculate NETWORKDAYS
  3. "N/A" because there isn't a need to calculate NETWORK days for that data set.
- I know some base formulas that could be used if I had only 2 variables

  - IF=(NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2)<0,"UNKNOWN",NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2))
  - IF=(B2="N/A","N/A",NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to combine the formulas:

> =IF(B2="N/A","N/A", IF(NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2)<0,"UNKNOWN",NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2)) )

Comment: Thank you so very much @LDC3! I spent an hour fighting Excel's formula checker to make this work before submitting the question.  I will keep this for future reference and not struggle so long before submitting a question.  :)

Comment: @Michelle: If this answer works for you, you should “accept” it by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: Greatest apologies.  I'm new to the site and use my phone a lot of the time.  Answer checked.